# Gspread - Can Not Retrieve Spreadsheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to use Gspread in Python2.7 to retrieve spreadsheets. I seem to be able to login but whenever I issue the command

```
gc.openall()
```

it just returns an empty list. I have given the service account admin access to everything and the sheets api is enabled in my google console. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Below is my `name-hash.json` file returned by Google and used to login:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "name-id",
  "private_key_id": "PRIVATE KEY ID",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
  ...
  \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "test@mname-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "CLIENTID",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/test-279%40name-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def login(json_key):
     scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
     credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_key, scope)
     gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
     return gc

gc = login('/Users/username/Downloads/name-hash.json')
files = gc.openall()
print(files)
    []
```

Comment: Is the sheet at the root of your google drive? It HAS to be for gspread to work. We have re-written our gspread using code to directly use the newest v4 google api. I strongly recommend it. It has a fairly steep learning curve but well worth it!

Comment: My guess is that you are missing sharing the spreadsheets themselves with the address: test@mname-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
If you try with open_by_key with one specific spreadsheet you will get an error message if that's the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of mainly 2 issues that could be at play here. First gspread may only access google sheets that are at the root of the google drive. To circumvent that, I strongly recommend moving to v4 google api python client instead of gspread.

If you do have google sheets in the root my guess is that you are missing sharing the spreadsheets themselves with the address: test@mname-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com

To verify that, I would suggest replacing openall with open_by_key and supply a single specific google sheet id to help debugging.

Comment: You were right, the problem was that I had to share the sheet with test@mname-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure :) I fought that library to death not long ago I definitely relate to the pain :)